# Volar and vue-tsc are showing different TS errors

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vscode-extensions, vite

In my Vite + Vue 3 + TypeScript project I have configured **vue-tsc** to run in **watch** mode while I am developing. I use **VS Code** with **Volar**. Now on one hand I have all my TS errors printed in the console which is what I was looking for. On the other hand I have extra errors from **vue-tsc**, but I don't have them from **Volar**.

For example,
I have one error saying that **state.month** is not assignable to type **Date**, but it is **Date**.

**vue-tsc**
[image: vue-tsc]

component, **volar** does not showing that error
[image: component, volar does not showing that error]

state in the component. As you see, **state.month** is **Date**
[image: state in the component]

Could someone help me, please? Did I missed something?

Comment: VSCode and your compiler may run different versions of TS.

Comment: Try to stop and start node server / VS code to see if it is fixed

Comment: @Duannx, thanks for answering. Tried multiple times, nothing's changed :(

Comment: @CodeWhisperer, thanks for answering! How can I check compiler's version of TS?

Comment: @Eduardo can you show your full code of that `state`'s definition? Try to push your code to an online playground like codesandbox.io so we can have a deeper look.

Comment: @Duannx thanks again, but I have already figured out what was the problem. CodeWhisperer's comment pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version of TypeScript in project's *package.json* and the version of TypeScript in VSCode were different. That was causing these weird errors. When I had updated the version in *package.json* to the same version VSCode has all errors were gone.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Another thing to check is that your vue-tsc package is up to date. Volar is a VS Code extension and gets auto-updated over time, while vue-tsc is an npm package, so npm will lock it to a version and it could get outdated.

That was the solution for me.
To get the latest & save for dev, run `npm i -D vue-tsc@latest`.

Reference in the Volar repo:
https://github.com/johnsoncodehk/volar/issues/1205